# Phone menu - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to make some project of phone Menu, with viewing, adding and removing contacts. Which way would be better, to add contact to dictionary or by making new file and write/read from it?

I tried first method - I had added new contact to empty dictionary and then I tried to view it by using viewing option but still dictionary is empty.

That's a first sample of my "project":

```
condition = True


while condition == True:
    print("Menu")
    print("contacts")
    print("Add contacts")
    print("Remove contacts")

    phone_contacts = {}

    def contacts(x):
        for item in dict(x):
            print(item, x[item])


    def add_contacts(x):
        new_key = input("Enter a name\n")
        new_value = input("Enter a number\n")
        x[new_key] = new_value
        print(phone_contacts)


    def remove_contacts(x):
        for item in dict(x):
            print(item)
        removing_contact = input("Enter a contact to remove\n")
        if removing_contact in x:
            del x[removing_contact]
            print("Contact has been deleted!")
        else:
            print("There is no '%s\' contact!") % (removing_contact)


    choose = input("Select option")

    if choose == "1":
        print(contacts(phone_contacts))
        choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU").lower()
        if choose_2 == "end":
            break
        elif choose_2 == "menu":
            pass

    elif choose == "2":
        print(add_contacts(phone_contacts))
        choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU").lower()
        if choose_2 == "end":
            break
        elif choose_2 == "menu":
            pass

    elif choose == "3":
        print(remove_contacts(phone_contacts))
        choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU").lower()
        if choose_2 == "end":
            break
        elif choose_2 == "menu":
            pass
    else:
        print("You didn't type anything!")
        choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU").lower()
        if choose_2 == "end":
            break
        elif choose_2 == "menu":
            pass
```

So this way doesn't work, I tried also write into a text.txt file

```
condition = True


while condition == True:
    print("Menu")
    print("contacts")
    print("Add contacts")
    print("Remove contacts")

    phone_contacts = {}

    def contacts(x):
        for item in dict(x):
            print(item, x[item])


    def add_contacts(x):
        new_key = input("Enter a name\n")
        new_value = input("Enter a number\n")
        text = "%s - %d" % (new_key, int(new_value))
        savefile = open("text.txt", "w")
        savefile.write(text)
        savefile.read(text)
        savefile.close()

    def remove_contacts(x):
        for item in dict(x):
            print(item)
        removing_contact = input("Enter a contact to remove\n")
        if removing_contact in x:
            del x[removing_contact]
            print("Contact has been deleted!")
        else:
            print("There is no '%s\' contact!") % (removing_contact)


    choose = input("Select option")

    if choose == "1":
        print(contacts(phone_contacts))
        choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU").lower()
        if choose_2 == "end":
            break
        elif choose_2 == "menu":
            pass

    elif choose == "2":
        print(add_contacts(phone_contacts))
        choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU").lower()
        if choose_2 == "end":
            break
        elif choose_2 == "menu":
            pass

    elif choose == "3":
        print(remove_contacts(phone_contacts))
        choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU").lower()
        if choose_2 == "end":
            break
        elif choose_2 == "menu":
            pass
    else:
        print("You didn't type anything!")
        choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU").lower()
        if choose_2 == "end":
            break
        elif choose_2 == "menu":
            pass
```

It doesn't work neither.

What am I doing wrong in both cases? Which way should I choose, first or the second one?

BTW I would be grateful for any tips how I could correct my code, even if those tips doesn't pertains to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both options you are overwriting the dictionary on every iteration. You should initilize it only once outside the loop. For the first option it will look like:

```
phone_contacts = {}             # this line moved from inside the loop

while condition == True:
    print("Menu")
    print("contacts")
    print("Add contacts")
    print("Remove contacts")

                                # the line deleted from here

    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define all functions before and outside the main while(True). You should turn the ifs block into a function that receives the input. 
You should make it explicit which key is which option.

```
list1=['a','b','c']

def operateList(number):
    if number == '3':
        try: list1.remove(input('Type what you want to remove:'))
        except: print('not in List')
    elif number == '2':
        list1.append(input('Type in what you want to add:'))
        list1.sort()
    elif number == '1':
        print(list1)



while(True):
    print('1: List')
    print('2: Add')
    print('3: Remove')
    operateList(input('Input option number:'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you have to declare phone_contacts and the functions outside of the loop.

Second there are redundancies in the conditions.

The idea of creating a file to store contacts is great. I would save it as a `.json` file as it is very simple to handle.

Here is the code, which I have refactored as well as I could.

```
import json


phone_contacts = {}


def print_contacts():
    if not phone_contacts:
        print("Empty list.")
        return

    for name, number in sorted(phone_contacts.items()):
        print(name, number)  # explicit is better than implicit


def add_contact():
    name = input("Enter a name\n")
    number = input("Enter a number\n")
    if name and number:
        phone_contacts[name] = number
        print("Contact added: {0}, {1}".format(name, number))


def remove_contacts():
    print_contacts()
    removing_contact = input("Enter a contact to remove\n")
    if removing_contact in phone_contacts:
        del phone_contacts[removing_contact]
        print("Contact has been deleted!")
    else:
        print("There is no '%s' contact!") % (removing_contact)


def load_contacts():
    global phone_contacts
    try:
        with open('contacts.json', 'r') as file:
            phone_contacts = json.load(file)
    except (ValueError, OSError):  # OSError catches FileNotFoundError
        phone_contacts = {}


def save_contacts():
    with open('contacts.json', 'w+') as file:
        json.dump(phone_contacts, file)


load_contacts()
while True:
    print("0. Exit")
    print("1. Menu")
    print("2. Add contact")
    print("3. Remove contacts")

    choose = input("Select option: ")

    if choose == "0":
        print("Exiting program...")
        break
    elif choose == "1":
        print_contacts()
    elif choose == "2":
        add_contact()
    elif choose == "3":
        remove_contacts()
    else:
        print("You didn't type a valid option!")

    # moved this block out as it's common to all options
    choose_2 = input("End/Back to MENU\n").lower()
    if choose_2 == "end":
        break
    # even if user typed anything different of menu
    # he/she would continue in the loop so that else was needless
save_contacts()
```

Also note that you don't need to pass phone_contacts as an argument since it's global.

I've added load and save contacts functions that is pretty understandable, even if you have no experience with JSON.

There's a lot of things to ask there so if you have some doubt and want to ask me, feel comfortable! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help me! Could you tell me why you used this "try/except" method in code? I tried to find some infromation about it but I don't get it. When I should use it and what's the purpose?

Comment: try/except is used for handling errors in your program. You should use it whenever your program does something that might run in an unexpected way in order to avoid this exception to crash your application. In this case, for example I used try/except to read the content that may not exist in a file that may not exist as well. So when the exception raises the code will just create an empty dictionary. Try to remove the try/except statement and run the code with and without the file contacts.json in the directory. Also [ask for forgiveness](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp)